# Data Factory Blob Source - Column Headers have meaning

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a bunch of csv files loaded into Azure blob storage with the following structure(s):

File1

Date, T1SensorFG1, T1SensorFG2, T1SensorFG3

1/1/16, 200, 300, 400

File2

Date, T2SensorFG1, T2SensorFG2, T2SensorFG3

1/1/16, 300,250, 345

So, essentially, two banks of sensors (T1 and T2) that emit three readings at a point in time.

I need to read this data in and apply the column headers to the rows so I know which bank each reading came from before subsequent processing.

Ideally the result of the pipeline should be something like this:

Bank, Date, FG1, FG2, FG3

T1, 1/1/16, 200, 300, 400

T2, 1/1/16, 300, 250, 345

I would be equally happy with a pivoted result if that's easier:

Bank, Date, Sensor, Value

T1, 1/1/16, FG1, 200

T1, 1/1/16, FG2, 300

T1, 1/1/16, FG3, 400

etc

I can't figure it out and I can't believe it's not possible.

Azure Blob is the source.  Destination/Sink can be blob and/or Azure SQL DB

Please can someone provide me some pointers to solving this.

Many, many thanks

Steve

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own transformation/processing logic using [custom copy activity](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-use-custom-activities/) and use the activity in a pipeline.